# Fullcalendar Duplicate entries on change of view

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm having trouble with duplicates when changing views on fullcalendar after an update.
I call the following function after and add/edit/erase or change of selected users.

```
var u=''; $('#tree1 li.user.jstree-checked').each(function() { u=u+'&Showuser='+$(this).attr('id'); });
       var jsonFeed = "cal.cgi?events=y"+u;
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', jsonFeed);
```

When in month view this works fine but in day or week view it also seems to work, e.g. no duplicates but then when I change to month view it reloads two or more sets of the feed.

I think that the `removeEvents` is only removing the events from the current view.

Maybe it's how I'm loading the events in the first place.

Comment: @MikeBently, I am facing the same issue. Fullcalendar requests duplicated `eventSources` after removing all original `eventSources` and adding new one. How did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation to remove previous event source
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/

removing previous event source and adding new event source will not cause duplicate events in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in mine was to remove all of the ID's from the calendar before adding new events, or the same events again for a different view.

```
for(var i=0;i<=json.events.length-1;i++){                                  
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar("removeEvents",json.events[i].id);
}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar("addEventSource",json);
```